# Dense layer does not give expected Output shape

Tags: machine-learning, keras, deep-learning, computer-vision, conv-neural-network

I am trying to copy a model architecture. In the original model architecture, after applying the last Dense layer Output Shape is (None, 3) with 300 params. As shown

```
 _________________________________________________________________
 Layer (type)                Output Shape              Param #   
 =================================================================

 dense_Dense1 (Dense)        (None, 100)               128100    
                                                             
 dense_Dense2 (Dense)        (None, 3)                 300
```

But when I apply the Dense output shape I am getting is (None, 3) with 303 params. as shown below

```
 _________________________________________________________________
 Layer (type)                Output Shape              Param #   
 =================================================================

 dense_35 (Dense)                (None, 100)          128100  

 dense_36 (Dense)                (None, 3)            303
```

This is the code I wrote for this part:

```
x = GlobalAveragePooling2D()(x)
x = Dense(100, activation="relu")(x)
prediction = Dense(3, activation='softmax')(x)
```

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that the architecture you're trying to copy doesn't use bias? Try [not using bias](https://keras.io/api/layers/core_layers/dense/):

```
Dense(3, activation='softmax', use_bias=False)
```

```
Model: "sequential_5"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
global_average_pooling2d_3 ( (None, 8)                 0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_9 (Dense)              (None, 100)               900       
_________________________________________________________________
dense_10 (Dense)             (None, 3)                 300       
=================================================================
Total params: 1,200
Trainable params: 1,200
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
```